# Local Global principle and Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

Let  $V$ be an A-module over a commutative ring $A$.

(a) Let $x,y \in V$. Then $x=y$ $\Leftrightarrow \frac {x}{1}=\frac{y}{1}$ in $V_M$ for all $M\in Spm A$.

If I have $x=y$ then for each $m\in M$ I will have $m(x-y)=0$. So, I am done.

Conversly, if $\frac {x}{1}=\frac{y}{1} $ in $V_M$ then I have $m\in M $ such that $m (x-y)=0 $ for all $M\in Spm A$. But I am not sure how exactly I should proceed with the proof.

(b) Prove that following statements are equivalent.

(i) $V=0$
(ii) $V_P = 0 $ for all $P\in Spec A$
(iii) $V_M =0$ for all $M\in Spec A$.

(iii) $\Rightarrow$(ii) holds as every maximal ideal is a prime ideal.

(i) $\Rightarrow$(iii) is clear.

**(ii) $\Rightarrow$ (i)** I am not getting any intuition on **how exactly should I approach this part** and would appreciate hints.

Kindly help.

Comment: You made a small error which may be why you are stuck.  You said, "if $\frac {x}{1}=\frac{y}{1} $ in $V_M$ then I have $m\in M $ such that $m (x-y)=0 $", but it should be: if $\frac {x}{1}=\frac{y}{1} $ in $V_M$ then I have $m\notin M $ such that $m (x-y)=0 $

Comment: Also when you say "$(iii)\implies (ii)$ holds as every maximal ideal is a prime ideal" you should say: $(ii)\implies (iii)$ holds as every maximal ideal is a prime ideal.  Also   if $(i)\implies (iii)$ is clear then $(i)\implies (ii)$ should be equally clear.   Thus the only one you need  to show is $(iii)\implies (i)$, which follows from part (a).

Comment: @tkf Ya, you are right.

Comment: @tkf do you mind helping how (a) should be approached?

Comment: Do you understand why: If $x,y\in V$ with $x\neq y$, then Ann$(x-y)\subseteq M$, for some maximal ideal $M$?

Comment: @tkf No. I think using the fact that if if x/1=y/1 in $V_M$ then I have m∉M such that  m(x−y)=0 , Ann(x-y) $\nsubseteq M$. But you are telling me the opposite.

Comment: That is exactly right.  What I said is also correct.  Combining the two we get the answer:  If $\frac x1=\frac y1$ in $V_M$ for every $M\in {\rm Spm} A$, then Ann$(x-y)\not\subseteq M$ for every $M\in {\rm Spm} A$, by what you said.  On the other hand by what I said, if we suppose $x\neq y$, then Ann$(x-y)\subseteq M$ for some $M\in {\rm Spm} A$, contradicting what you said.  Conclusion: We cannot have $x\neq y$.  Hence we have $x=y$.  $${}$$ So you understand why your last comment is true, and  if you also understand why my previous comment is true, then we are done - yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints.** For (a), you can always assume $y=0$. So you have to prove that $x=0$ if and only if $x/1=0/1$ for all maximal ideals $M$.

Assume that $x\neq 0$. Show that $Ann(x)$ is an ideal different from $A$. Hence it is contained in some maximal ideal $M_0$. Then prove that $x/1\neq 0/1$ in $V_{M_0}$ by contradiction.

For $(b)$, just apply $(a)$ with $y=0$.

Comment: Why I am allowed to always assume y=0? Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: do you mind replying?

Comment: $x=y\iff  x-y=0$, and $x/1=y/1 \iff (x-y)/1=0/1$.

Comment: Why you are sure that Ann(x)  can't be equal to A?

Comment: Can you please reply if you have some time to spare?

Comment: Show that $1\notin Ann(x)$.